# Is it possible to use Kotlin Native on macOS 10.12?

Tags: opengl, kotlin-native

I'm trying to port a simple Go macOS application over to Kotlin Native.  After struggling with various errors I decided to take a step back, and have a look at the official examples provided with Kotlin Native.

I found a basic OpenGL example here:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/opengl

But so far I haven't been able to get this to compile.

I tried downloading the complete sources for Kotlin, but that wont build.  I followed a few suggestions generated at build time, including the change to 'ignoreXcodeVersionCheck' and downloading prebuilt binaries for the compiler, but at this point I'm wondering if this just isn't supported by my environment?  I do understand that this is all experimental.

I've attached a sample of errors below, but I'm not sure whats relevant.

**Question**: Does anyone else have this setup / environment working please? can I expect to get it working?

macos 10.12.4,  kotlin 1.3.11,  xcode 8.2.1

```
.konan/dependencies/clang-llvm-6.0.1-darwin-macos/include/c++/v1/cmath:551:28: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR typename enable_if<is_floating_point<_A1>::value, bool>::type

.konan/dependencies/clang-llvm-6.0.1-darwin-macos/include/c++/v1/cstddef:44:15: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
#include_next <stddef.h>

    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'kotlin-native-master'.
 expected Xcode version 10.1, got 8.2.1, consider updating Xcode or use "ignoreXcodeVersionCheck" variable in konan.properties

kotlin-native-master/runtime/src/main/cpp/ObjCExportErrors.mm:73:23: error: no type or protocol named 'NSErrorUserInfoKey'
  NSMutableDictionary<NSErrorUserInfoKey, id>* userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary new] autorelease];

.konan/dependencies/clang-llvm-6.0.1-darwin-macos/include/c++/v1/cmath:313:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
```

Comment: It works on macOS 10.14.3 with Xcode 10.1

Comment: thanks, I have given up with Kotlin Native for now.  I did get a 'hello world' running eventually... but everything seems very pre-alpha at the moment, no documentation, or tests to show usage.  I know KN is all still very experimental, but I got the same OpenGL stuff running with Go in under an hour, and the compile time is about a second...  Seems like KN has a long way to go, but good to hear it does work somewhere, thanks.

Comment: @Peter can you please let me know, where to add `ignoreXcodeVersionCheck` option? I'm really stuck...I'm using it as a plugin not the actual kotlin native source code

Comment: @touhid udoy - ignoreXcodeVersionCheck was in the konan.properties file in the konan subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get a "hello world" working under the above environment, but I have given up with the OpenGL stuff.  I cant update my environment currently, and I guess this issue doesn't affect many people.  So I'm going to close it with this 'answer'.